# How to parse interaction messages coming from Slack?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I want to parse interaction message requests coming from Slack. This is what Slack says in [their docs](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity/enabling#understanding_payloads):

> The body of that request will contain a payload parameter. Your app
>   should parse this payload parameter as JSON.

That seemed straightforward, so I parsed it like so:

```
JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(body.split('=')[1]))
```

However, in the string-fields of the resulting object, I see pluses instead of spaces:

```
"There+should+not+be+pluses+here"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took a look at [their library here](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-interactive-messages/blob/master/src/http-handler.js#L47), and it turns out, they use node's `querystring.parse()`.

So the parsing procedure should look like this:

```
JSON.parse(querystring.parse(body).payload)
```

Comment: `payload` is a standard HTML form parameter in the request. Therefore best to use library methods to parse them.